# Stack Overflow search plugin for Eclipse

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

Are there any Eclipse plugins available for searching Stack Overflow web content inside Eclipse only?

Does Stack Overflow provide any APIs to public for developing such plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I've just published it, check it out:

https://github.com/MarounMaroun/SO-Eclipse-Plugin

## SO Eclipse Plug-in

Enables you to get answers from Stack Overflow directly to Eclipse!

### Features

Right click on the editor, then select "Ask me". The following window will appear:

[image: Ask me]

Clicking on "OK" will open a dialog that includes answers that links to Stack Overflow from Google:

[image: Answers]

Pressing on "Next" and "Previous" will take you to the next/previous answers.

### Installation

- Help > Install New Software... > Add
- Insert "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MarounMaroun/SO-Eclipse-Plugin/master/so-eclipse-update-site/site.xml"
- Click OK and proceed with the installation process

### Running Locally

- Download [Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/)
- File > Import...
- General > Existing Projects into Workspace
- Select root directory > Browse...
- Choose the project's root

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is [one listed on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/1087/stacklipse-eclipse-plugin-preview), but it looks fairly abandoned. I don't know of anything more recent, although there is something for code snippet searching [inside Visual Studio](https://stackapps.com/questions/4353/flow-code-editor-extension).

As far as creating one goes, [the API documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com) provides a pretty good overview. There are also [some libraries on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library) that can make working with the API easier.